# Speech Recognition API without Grammar C#

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, grammar

I am developing a program where 99% of the time i can use a set Grammar in the standard Microsoft Speech Recognition to detect words being said. However in a few circumstances, i need the user to say something. This is never going to be predictable.

So is there a way to do this with the MS speech recognition?

And are there any other speech recognition API's out there (for free), that can handle non-preset words?

Comment: [Microsoft Tellme](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/tellme/) will be able to do this, but it's not available for Developers yet. Tellme is what powers WP7, Kinect, and Ford Sync speech recognition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a class called [DictationGrammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar.aspx) that allows you to recognize dictated speech.

It also supports a "dictation context" - so you can specify that the dictated text should start/end with a specific phrase.

I think that would do the trick - technically, it's still a grammar, but it seems to fit what you're looking for.