# C# speech recognition without predefined grammar

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

I'm  trying to use speech recognition with C# application but this way I have only predicted phrase on output:

```
sList.Add(new string[] { "hello", "test", "works", "exit"});
```

Can I get output same way like Google Speech Recognition API work, recognize speech, not exist words and give me on output, or if I can use Google Speech Recognition with C# would be good to see some example how to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speech Recognition API without Grammar C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229187/speech-recognition-api-without-grammar-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new Grammar, create a new DictationGrammar.  This loads a standard dictionary, but the accuracy will be lower than if you provided it with a separate grammar.

Comment: yes exactly, but recognition not too accurate if you do not speak like a robot