# VOCE speech Recognition without grammar

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, voce

I am a beginner in `Java` and `speech recognition` and I am using `VOCE` (http://voce.sourceforge.net/) to transform speech to text.

I used the provided example and it worked by recognizing only words specified in `.gram` file. However, I need the app to recognize much more words than the words specified in the grammar file.

I found this similar question ([Speech Recognition API without Grammar C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229187/speech-recognition-api-without-grammar-c-sharp)) but I do not if the solution is applicable in `VOCE`.

So is there a way to do this with `VOCE` speech recognition?

And are there any other speech recognition API's out there (for free)capable of doing so?

Comment: You already asked it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228844/voce-speech-recognition-and-language-model

Comment: Simply do not use voce

Comment: my previous question was on hold, so i paraphrased it and narrowed down my problem

Comment: Your second question is not better than the first one.

Comment: you might be a professional and high level programmer but not all have the same level of knowledge. how about helping instead of destructive criticism? I would appreciate it if you provided any tips on either good question writing or how to solve my problem.  Don't waste your time replying to my questions if you can not add value to me or other users of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the developer of VOCE and he replied as "There is no easy way to do so"
I solved my problem by using Sphinx4 Transcriber Demo that uses a language model instead than a specific grammar file.